# Shared folder Virtualbox Ubuntu / Lubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, shared-folders

I can see a lot of posts on this but they either don't cover what I'm trying, the OS's that I'm using or (most likely) I'm not understanding them.

I'm using Ubuntu 14, and I have VirtualBox running Lubuntu. I want to create a shared folder.

I've created a folder in the home directory of the host system
I've gone into the VM and in the VM using the menu :

```
Machine > Settings > Shared Folders > Add New Shared Folder (Icon)
```

This opens up the options for choosing a directory - I choose the one that I've just set up on the Host system.

I can't access this though. After rebooting the VM I can't look inside the directory, though it does appear in `/media`

[image]

I've changed the permissions on the folder in the Main System so that anyone can access it, I'm not sure why the VM can't.

Not too sure what to do here..

---

EDIT

Reading [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/SharedFolders)

I get the following error :

```
vco@geoHP:~$ sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=$UID,gid=$(id -g) share ~/host
[sudo] password for vco: 
mount: mount point /home/vco/host does not exist
```

EDIT #2

After creating a directory called host in my Host's home directory I get the following error :

```
vco@geoHP:~$ sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=$UID,gid=$(id -g) share ~/host
[sudo] password for vco: 
mount: unknown filesystem type 'vboxsf'
vco@geoHP:~$
```

EDIT #3

Trying to run the above command from the Virtual Machine rather than the Host system I get the following error :

```
klak@klakBox:~$ sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=$UID,gid=$(id -g) share ~/host
[sudo] password for klak: 
/sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: No such file or directory
klak@klakBox:~$
```

Comment: After you set the shared folder on host, did you [mounted it on guest](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/SharedFolders)?

Comment: @Cornelius thanks, I've tried that and edited the OP with the errors -> I'm getting `unknown filesystem`, though I have vm additions installed on the VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to still Mount it. Try to look into this, the Mount command. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

Update:
Better yet, try this command.
`sudo mount -t cifs //ip_of_host/share/path /local/mount/dir`

Comment: thanks @xR, I've edited the OP... the errors that I'm getting are in there.

Comment: link you sent is for windows shares - both these systems are Linux... If you know anything re the updated errors that would be ace.

Comment: i've sorted it now, have a tick

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is:

```
sudo usermod -a -G vboxsf _user_
```

It's all about group permission. Once you have that, you can access the folders. You can see that if you can access such folders under, e.g., `sudo ls -l /media/sf_vmShare`.

And don't forget to relogin so the new "group" permission will be set.